# time complexity of reversing a linked list

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures

I wrote the following function to reverse a linkedlist and was wondering about the time complexity of the 'swapping'. my rationale is as follows:
it is o(n)

insertion/deletion in a linkedlist is o(1), but that assumes just adding to the tail or removing from the head/tail. here you are iterating and accessing each element, and accessing elements in a linked list is o(n).
is that correct? generally, what is the time complexity of swaps?

```
LinkedList.prototype.reverse = function () {
  var previous = null;
  var current = this.head;
  var next;
  while (current) {
    //swap pointers
    //cache iteration/temp var
    next = current.next;
    //point the next to the previous
    current.next = previous;
    //previous is the current one
    previous = current;

    //iterate
    current = next;
  }
  //after you're done set the head to null (ie make it the tail)
  this.head = null;
};
```

Comment: why the head of linkedList set to null after reverse done?  shouldn't it be the tail element? how can you iterating a linkedlist if the head is null?

Comment: since the linkedlist is now reversed the head *is* the tail now :) after the reverse is done, you don't need to iterate anymore anyways.

Comment: ok... maybe this is the requirement of your business, I just think a linkedlist should be a linkedlist after reverse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time complexity of linked list algorithms will depend on whether you start with the place in the list you want to operate.

Insertion/deletion is O(1) if you know and O(n) if you have to iterate to find it.

The same is true for swap.

Reversing a singly-linked list is O(n) since you must touch every single node. There is a data structure trick for which reversing a doubly-linked list is O(1). You use a bit to maintain which direction counts as "forward".